# How to write a regular expression that can capture multiple lines into one capture group?

Tags: java, regex

### The Problem

In my application we are pulling notes that look like this:

```
****************************
Example noteText 
krishna  2023-05-16T11:29:59Z

****************************

*****************************
Example notes for testing
Extension of the same notes

2023-05-16T11:36:03Z
******************************
```

Then we need to convert the notes to JSON. The result needs to be formatted like the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:29:59Z",
    "userid": "krishna",
    "content": "Example noteText"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:36:03Z",
    "userid": "krishna",
    "content": "Example notes for testing  Extension of the same notes"
  } 
]
```

### Attempted Solution

My current solution is a regular expression in Java that unfortunately cannot capture multi-line note content in one capture group. This causes the output to separate one multi-line note into two notes.

#### Code

```java
Pattern notesPattern = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:\\*{25}\\r\\n)" +
    "(?<date>[\\w\\s:]+?)" +
    "\\r\\n" +
    "(?<userid>\\w+?)" +
    "\\r\\n" +
    "(?:\\*{25}\\r\\n)" +
    "(?<content>.+)" + // Note content is captured here
    "(?:\\r\\n\\r\\n)?");
```

#### Output

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:29:59Z",
    "userid": "krishna",
    "content": "Example noteText"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:36:03Z",
    "userid": "krishna",
    "content": "Example notes for testing "
  },
  {
    "timestamp": null,
    "userid": null,
    "content": "\n\nExtension of the same notes"
  }
]
```

How can I modify my regular expression to capture multiple lines in one capture group?

Comment: Can you post your complete current working code in java that is giving you this output?

Comment: @krishna-lakshmi If my dotall flag solution (or any of the other solutions) haven't worked for you, could you comment what issues you're having. If a solution has worked, can you mark one as the answer, please

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'm not sure how you got the results you did with code you've shown, so it's a bit difficult to understand exactly what your regular expression does. However, it seems like your main issue is that the content capture group in your regular expression is using `.+` to try to match anything. By default, `.` doesn't match line terminators (e.g. `\r` and `\n`), so you have a few options.

### Solutions

#### The dotall flag

This is probably the right solution for you here. After you include the dotall flag, `.+` will match line terminators as well. This will allow you to easily match multiple lines of arbitrary note content.

```java
Pattern.compile("pattern", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

#### Non-capturing group with alternations between `.` and line terminators

This solution is also fairly effective if you can't use the dotall flag. It allows you to check for `.` or a line terminator and use the `+` quantifier to check for that 1 or more times.

```
/(?:.|\r|\n)+/
```

#### Character set including line terminators

You can include line terminators in a character set that includes all of the characters you wish to allow in the note content. This is not a very good solution as it limits the note content to whatever characters you remember to include.

```
/[\w\s!@#$%^&*()=+[\]{}"':;<>,.?|\\~`\r\n]+/
```

### Complete regular expression

As I couldn't reproduce the results you got with your own regular expression. I've started from scratch and written one that should match your requirements.

[View this solution at RegExr](https://regexr.com/7dvvl)

```
/^\*+$\n(?<content>.+?)\n^(?:(?<userid>\w+)  )?(?<timestamp>\d+-\d+-\d+T\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ)$\n+^\*+$/gms
```

It should be noted that I didn't include `\r` since RegExr doesn't have carriage return characters only `\n` newline characters. However, this should be super easy to fix.

#### Results

- Match 0

  - content: `Example noteText`
  - userid: `krishna`
  - timestamp: `2023-05-16T11:29:59Z`
- Match 1

  - content: `Example notes for testing\nExtension of the same notes`
  - userid: *empty*
  - timestamp: `2023-05-16T11:36:03Z`

Answer (score 0):

First, regular expression captures have to be in the order they appear.

Secondly, you cannot merge capture groups, unfortunately.

My recommendation is to just read the note line-for-line with a `BufferedReader`.

You can use a class to hold the `timestamp` and `content`, and another class to hold the `userid` and a list of `content`.

```java
class Note {
    String userid;
    List<Content> content;
}

class Content {
    String timestamp;
    String string;

    void append(String string) {
        this.string += System.lineSeparator() + string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join(" ", string.split("\r\n?|\n"));
    }
}
```

I've included a `toString` method in the `Content` class, as it appears you want the strings appended on one line.

Then, create a method called `parse`, which returns a `Note`.
The regular expression within this method is attempting to match the timestamp.

```java
Note parse(String string) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string))) {
        String line;
        int indexOf;
        Note note = new Note();
        Content content = null;
        List<Content> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty() && !line.matches("\\*+")) {
                if (line.matches(".*\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z")) {
                    indexOf = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
                    if (content == null) content = new Content();
                    if (indexOf != -1) {
                        note.userid = line.substring(0, indexOf).strip();
                        content.timestamp = line.substring(indexOf + 1);
                    } else
                        content.timestamp = line;
                    list.add(content);
                    content = null;
                } else {
                    if (content == null) {
                        content = new Content();
                        content.string = line;
                    } else
                        content.append(line);
                }
            }
        }
        note.content = list;
        return note;
    }
}
```

Finally, add a `toString` method to your `Note` class, to build the JSON object.

```java
class Note {
    String userid;
    List<Content> content;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        String newline = System.lineSeparator();
        json.append('[').append(newline);
        int index = 0;
        for (Content string : content) {
            json.append("{".indent(2));
            json.append("\"timestamp\": \"%s\"".formatted(string.timestamp).indent(4));
            json.append("\"userid\": \"%s\"".formatted(userid).indent(4));
            json.append("\"content\": \"%s\"".formatted(string).indent(4));
            if (++index != content.size()) json.append("},".indent(2));
            else json.append("}".indent(2));
        }
        json.append(']');
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

If you were to run `parse` on your input string, and then printed the `Note`, you would get the following.

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:29:59Z"
    "userid": "krishna"
    "content": "Example noteText "
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-16T11:36:03Z"
    "userid": "krishna"
    "content": "Example notes for testing Extension of the same notes"
  }
]
```